# How to programmatically change the parameters of Windows NIC driver?

Tags: windows, driver, windows-kernel, network-driver

I need to write the code to set MTU size, RX/TX Queue size, and Interrupt moderation mode.
Can you please suggest what API could be used for such purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [SetMtu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/setmtu-method-in-class-win32-networkadapterconfiguration) Function of `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` class in WMI

Comment: Thanks. It is exactly what I need.